# Difference in inserting values into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012

The query is:

```
drop table x
create table x(id int primary key)

insert into x values(5)
insert into x values(6)

begin tran
insert into x values(1),(2),(3),(3),(4)--Primary key violation 
commit tran

select* from x
```

This returns

```
5
6
```

and another query

```
drop table x
create table x(id int primary key)

insert into x values(5)
insert into x values(6)

begin tran
insert into x values(1)

insert into x values(2)
insert into x values(3)
insert into x values(3) --Primary key violation
insert into x values (4)
commit tran

select * from x
```

This returns

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

So what is the difference in inserting values in SQL Server?

Between those 2 queries and why the different result sets?

Comment: You might also want to check XACT_ABORT: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Sample 1 has a single insert statement for the 1,2,3,3,4,5. This is a "bulk" insert statement (however SQL Server uses the term bulk insert in a different fashion). Essentially it means all the inserts in this line are executed as 1 single action.

Sample 2 has separate insert statements. Since there is no exception handling in place, there is no reason for the transaction to abort. The error is ignored, the other records are added, and the result is then what you see.

Answer (score 0):

SQL server executes the queries as batches. So if any error occurs in the batch, [according to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712439(v=vs.85).aspx), one the following is possible.

> - No statements in the batch are executed.
> - No statements in the batch    are executed and the transaction is rolled back.
> - All of the    statements before the error statement are executed.
> - All of the    statements except the error statement are executed.

In your first case, "No statements in the batch are executed". And in your second case, "All of the statements except the error statement or executed".

For more about SQL batches, please refer the following MSDN articles,

- [Batches of SQL Statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712553(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Executing Batches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms716359(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Errors and Batches](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712439(v=vs.85).aspx)